# How to implement JSON Schema Faker with Angular 4 and above

Tags: javascript, json, angular, json-schema-faker

Is it possible to use JSON Schema faker as a third party dependency in Angular. I tried to use the dependency injection to Angular however in the providers I am not able to import jsonSchemaFaker.

angular.json

```
"scripts": [
    "./node_modules/json-schema-faker/dist/json-schema-faker.bundle.min.js"
]
```

jsonSchemaFaker.service.ts

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
export const JSF_Token = new InjectionToken ('jsonSchemaFaker');
```

app.module.ts

```
providers: [
    { provide: JSF_Token, useValue: jsf }
]
```

...

```
declare let jsf: any;
```

This is what I tried to Inject json schema faker as a dependency in my angular app.. I am getting .. Uncaught ReferenceError: jsf is not defined

Comment: Please provide some potentially incomplete code of what you're trying to achieve so SO users will better understand your requirements

Comment: @NinoFiliu .. I've added the code (in my query) that I used to work with JSON Schema Faker in my angular application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change my providers and the declaration to

```
providers: [
    { provide: JSF_Token, useValue: JSONSchemaFaker }
]

declare let JSONSchemaFaker: any;
```

Reason: the global name for JSON Schema Faker mentioned in that library is "JSONSchemaFaker". It was a mistake on my part to declare it as jsf.

Answer (score 1):

That is not how you use npm packages in an angular application.

First off, navigate to the directory of your `package.json` in your application and install the package:

```
npm install json-schema-faker
```

Then, inside your components or your services, use it as such:

```
// at the top of your file, next to other imports
import jsf from 'json-schema-faker';

// json-schema-faker is now available in the rest of your file as jsf

// you can, for example, have a service method that returns that:
jsf.generate({type: 'string'})
```

Comment: I tried above steps however I am getting some warnings and errors.
WARNING in ./node_modules/escodegen/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-map/source-map-generator.js 8:45-52
Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
ERROR in ./node_modules/jsonpath/generated/parser.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\projects\esb\Coupler\frontend\client\node_modules\jsonpath\generated'

Comment: I don't have enough infos to debug your issue. If you require further help, please put your code inside a clonable git repo

Comment: I have tried an stackblitz implementation. However I am unable to continue with the implementation.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-json-schema-faker-implement